# Getting postion of list item from ListView having button

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I want to get the item clicked in the listView.I have searched alot on the net,Found some solution in which a new class is created with extending adapter class and then getView() method being called but its not working for me coz i m Populating the data from my database.
I want my textView also to be clickable but I m stuck on the button so if u can help then please help me for both clickable button and textView.

This is my listView xml where onClick="navigateToMap"

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtbbName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtbbaddr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtloc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtbbName"
        android:layout_marginRight="38dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtbbaddr"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="Navigate" 
        android:onClick="navigateToMap"/>


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This my Activity which is being loading on a button pressed from other Activity.
Just tried to get the value of the textview in the navigateToMap() code when i click on it,it gives me a toast but displays the wrong value(The value of the above list item).

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BloodBank extends Activity {
    ListView bloodbanklst;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_blood_bank);

         String[] arrayColumns = new String[]{"name","addr","longitude","latitude","location","ph_no1","ph_no2"};
         int[] arrayViewIDs = new int[]{R.id.txtbbName,R.id.txtbbaddr,R.id.txtloc};
         Context context;
         bloodbanklst=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.bloodbankList);



         DataBaseHelper myDbHelper;
         myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
         SQLiteDatabase db=myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select * from bloodBank", null);
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.blooddisplaylist,c,arrayColumns, arrayViewIDs);
    bloodbanklst.setAdapter(adapter);





    }

    public void navigateToMap(View view){
        TextView txt1=(TextView) findViewByIdR.id.txtloc);
        String abc = (String) txt1.getText();
        Toast.makeText(this,"Value from the text"+ abc,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.blood_bank, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get your text by using getText() from a Textview specified in XML.  While that's fine for a layout, a Listview will have many - dozens, or even hundreds of the same Textview as you will inflate that view for each list item.  navigateToMap() doesn't know WHICH textview you want to pull from.

You should use an onItemClickListener to list for clicks and call navigateToMap with the view
that was clicked

Something like this:

```
 item.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {            

               navigateToMap(view)   // this passes the view you inflated and filled         
                                     //with data, bot just the XML that defines 
                                     //what it looks like

            }
     });
```

Then

```
 public void navigateToMap(View view){
    TextView txt1=(TextView) view.getChildAt(some index)   // find which child first
    String abc = (String) txt1.getText();
    Toast.makeText(this,"Value from the text"+ abc,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: When i do this in my navigate method i dont get the method getChildAt() and how do i get the postion should i pass the postion variable also when it calls this method
TextView txt1=(TextView) view.getChildAt(some index)